# Best strategy for generating floats with minimum amount of risk

Tags: equities, arbitrage, strategy, put-call-parity, insurance

I'm looking for a way to get cash-in-hand in exchange for future obligation.

For example, I can sell deep-in-the-money puts and buy out-of-the-money puts (for hedge) with expiration of 2 years, The problem here is that it can lead to a loss of more than double the received amount.

Is there a way for me to get paid with low risk of my obligation? (something like insurance policy)?

Thank you

Comment: The premium should equal the risk. If there was a known area where risk were (temporarily) undervalued, the  the market would buy it and the price would be pushed up until it was fair. That is, why is anyone going to sell you something for less than it's expected value?

Comment: @will I'm willing to pay an appropriate interest for this, just not 200% as in the put example

Comment: The example you give "like an insurance policy" can end up having to pay out many times the premium. And in all massively otm trades, the potential payoff is many times the premium, since it is extremely unlikely.